Pivoting table without specifying value in snowflake
I have a table like below.
-- Sample data setup
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE your_table 
(
    ID VARCHAR(50),
    EntityName VARCHAR(50),
    Value VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO your_table (ID, EntityName, Value)
VALUES
    ('IL15342506861', 'AAP_DENOM', '02107'),
    ('IL15342506861', 'AAP_DENOM_PYCM', '098'),
    ('IL15342506861', 'AAP_DENOM_PYEM', '2154'),
    ('IL15342506861', 'AAP_NUM', '3241'),
    ('IL15342506861', 'AAP_NUM_PYEM', '215'),
    ('IL15342506861', 'AGE', '23'),
    ('IL15342506213', 'AAP_DENOM_PYEM', '134'),
    ('IL15342506213', 'AGE', '12');


I want result like below.

I have to create view that works without specifying EntityName in the query because EntityName may vary, which means I don't want to add manual EntityName while writing query.
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW pivoted_view AS
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'AAP_DENOM' THEN Value END) AS AAP_DENOM,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'AAP_DENOM_PYCM' THEN Value END) AS AAP_DENOM_PYCM,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'AAP_DENOM_PYEM' THEN Value END) AS AAP_DENOM_PYEM,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'AAP_NUM' THEN Value END) AS AAP_NUM,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'AAP_NUM_PYEM' THEN Value END) AS AAP_NUM_PYEM,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'AGE' THEN Value END) AS AGE
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ID

I heard that we can create JavaScript function that will create function and we can use it while creating view. but I don't have that much knowledge. Please help me with requirement.

If you search the Snowflake documentation for “dynamic pivot” there are plenty of examples for how to do this

@NickW after your comment I checked that, but I have to create view from pivot query.  we can not EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in view as I have check.

The dynamic pivot part is easy so let's start with that.
create or replace table pivoted_table as 

select *
from your_table
pivot(max(value) for entityname in (any order by entityname))
order by id;

select * 
from pivoted_table;


You'll see that dynamic pivot added single quotes around pivoted columns to preserve original values. You actually want that if your entityname column has values with spaces or special characters. But if your column values are already "pivot friendly" and you'd rather select col than select "'col'", we can fix this in the post.
--use a scripting block to rename quoted columns to unquoted column name

declare
  stmt_list cursor for select distinct 'alter table pivoted_table rename column '||$$"'$$||entityname||$$'"$$||' to '||entityname||';' as stmt from your_table;
  query varchar;
begin
  for item in stmt_list do
    query:= item.stmt;
    execute immediate :query;
  end for;  
  return 'Column names successfully renamed';
end;

--create your view on top of the pivoted table whose column names we fixed above

create or replace pivoted_view as
select *
from pivoted_table;

select * from pivoted_view;

